# 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'

Tags: web-server, internet-explorer

http://mts.varicentondemand.com
URL is correct. It worked the other day. URL to pointing at db server and db was edited this morning in 'jdbc.properties' file and is correct.  Nothing wrong with the pointers in that sense.  To pick up the changes 'Apache Tomcat 6 was restarted.  Everything should work, but the page is not coming up.  Tried URL form local as well as the web/app server itself.  Where to check for clues?

Comment: Is this problem specific to Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

> Where to check for clues?

Try looking in the Tomcat logs.